# Size of a hex in GDB's x memory-dump command

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm trying to try all the variants of the `x` command in assembly. I typed

```
(gdb) x /x $rsp
0x7fffffffdf90: 0x01
```

According to my book the x/x command select the first 8 bytes from rsp and write them as an hex. However, looking for the assembly documentation (gdb help) i have not found anywhere that the size of /x is explicitly 8 byte. So how do I know if it is really 8 bytes ?

Comment: Use a count larger than 1 to see what the grouping is, and what the gap is to the next address.  Or dump something that definitely doesn't have zeros in the high bytes, because `0x01` and `0x00000001` might both print the same, but `0xDEADBEEF` is unambiguously (at least) 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

> So how do I know if it is really 8 bytes ?

It's not. It's "whatever size you used last". [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html).

For example:

```
(gdb) x/bx $rsp
0x7fffffffcbc8: 0x1c
```

Subsequent `x/x` commands will use size 1 (a single char):

```
(gdb) x/x $rsp
0x7fffffffcbc8: 0x1c
```

You can override the size explicitly:

```
(gdb) x/gx $rsp
0x7fffffffcbc8: 0x00007ffff7ddc61c
```

Subsequent `x/x` commands now default to size 8:

```
(gdb) x/x $rsp
0x7fffffffcbc8: 0x00007ffff7ddc61c
```